# How add field to latest.yml generated by electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

Due electron 23 stopped support windows 7, how can i prevent autoupdate my app on win7 if new version based on electron >23?
Only way i see, on event `update-available` get info from `latest.yml`, but how add this info to generated latest.yml file?
Can i add custom field, or something else?